# !== in Codeigniter 3.1.9

Tags: codeigniter-3

I faced one issue when upgrade codeigniter 2.2.0 into 3.1.9

$this->input->post('q') have a empty value. In Codeigniter 2.2.0, the below condition not satisfied, But In Codeigniter 3.1.9, It's satisfied and went inside the condition. Why it's differ ?

```
if ($this->input->post('q') !== false){
//
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$this->input->post('q')`? i.e. `die(var_dump($this->input->post('q')))`? Is it now not `false`?

Comment: Value of $this->input->post('q') is Empty. When print using var_dump means It's return NULL

Comment: Well there you go. `null !== false` and therefore your statement will be satisfied

Comment: Yeah ok. But why it's not satisfied in codeigniter 2.2.0.

Comment: Because in 2.2.0 it wasn't `null`, it was `false`. 2.x and 3.x are called "Major" releases. Often major releases in anything (frameworks, languages, anything) are not fully backward compatible. Minor relases, i.e. 3.1.8 and 3.1.9 will usually be backward compatible within the realm of that major release using "Deprecation" warnings to flag things that may crap out later although that's not always the case.

Comment: Great Thanks!. So In Codeigniter 2.2.0 empty value are return as false. In Codeigniter 3.1.9 empty value are return as NULL. I'm Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180524/discussion-between-raja-c-and-ggdx).

Comment: I'd say that if it's programatically empty, it should be NULL because that's what NULL means (but that's just my opinion). If that's what your tests are showing, I'm not going to argue with you. This is not a CI specific question but a general one regarding correct return values that CI seem to have now adopted. It may have been the case that they returned FALSE previously because of `if(!$this->input->post('q')){` making marginally more sense for conditionals

Comment: Fine. Thank you!!